# How to fetch the newest 10 posts from 10 categories in one MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections of documents (named posts) that each contain a field named category.
Each category is part of a categories collection. There are a fixed number of them (say 15).

How do I fetch the last 10 tldrs from each category?

Comment: how do you define "last 10" - are you keeping a date on the documents, I assume, and then you want 10 "most recent"?

Comment: yes I have a createdAt field that records the timestamp, by last I meant newest, sorry for being unclear I edited the question.

Comment: there isn't a way to do it in a single query - you probably need mapreduce for this - how "performant" does this need to be?  And how "real time"?

Comment: this needs to be as real time as possible. (it's for a discover page). For now I do it with 11 queries. First I fetch the categories and then for each category I fetch the newest posts. It is fast enough but I'm pretty sure it's not optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to set a "flag" in each post which is actually part of the result, like:

```
topTen: true
```

Defining a sparse index on that flag would give the fastest query - at the price, of course, of the maintenance of that flag:

- set the flag at insertion time (impact: one more index to update)
- if it is tolerable that for a certain period the query returns 11 posts instead of 10, then trigger a background process that deletes (unsets) the 11th flag for that category
- if it is not tolerable, find and unset the 11th flag at insert time
- if the category of an existing post is altered, make sure the flags get set all right (for the old and the new category)
- if a post gets removed that has the flag set: find and set the flag for the new 10th post
- may be you'd want to provide a periodically ran process, that makes sure the flags are all set as they should be

For more information on sparse indexes, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-sparse

Answer (score 1):

Probably it will be better to just at first get the list of all categories and then for each of them get their 10 latest posts by separate queries.